# Static func to generate random type in enum causes crash with error "unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, function, enums, static, null

So I got the basis for this code from a tutorial on Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1

The problem is that occasionally when the function is called it crashes the app and returns the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" I am pretty sure the nil value comes from the rawValue that is being set.

My Code:

```
enum VillianType: Int {
case Unknown = 0, ammo, money, one, two, three

static func random() -> VillianType {
    return VillianType(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(6)) + 1)!
}

var spriteName: String {

    let spriteNames = [
        "ammo",
        "money",
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ]

    return spriteNames[rawValue]
}
}
```

I understand the basic concepts of what is going on here, but this is the first time that I have tried working with enums so please explain your answer in depth. My question is how can I fix the error, and why is it occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range for the random numbers is too big.

Change:

```
arc4random_uniform(6)
```

to:

```
arc4random_uniform(5)
```

`arc4random_uniform(6)` returns values `0` through `5`.  When it is `5` and you add `1` and get `6`, then `VillianType(rawValue: 6)` returns `nil` because there is no `enum` value corresponding to `6` and the force unwrap `!` causes it to crash.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was over complicating my thought process because I don't understand enums very well. Thanks for your help it works great!